# Allow special characters in text field

Tags: php, html, yii, character

I'm trying to modify an input field that doesn't allow special characters to do allow it. Here is the piece of code that I'm working with.

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('class'=>'form-control','onkeyup'=> 'return IsAlphaNumeric(event)')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>
```

It seems like the middle PHP line is the one causing it to block special characters I just don't know how to go about editing it to allow the special characters.

Here is the entire  code in the file that I'm working on:

```
<?php
/* @var $this CategoriesController */
/* @var $model Categories */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'categories-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
 'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data','onsubmit'=> 'return validateCategory()'),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">
    <?php echo Yii::t('admin' , 'Fields with'); ?>
        <span class="required"> * </span>
        <?php echo Yii::t('admin', 'are required.'); ?>
    </p>

    <?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('class'=>'form-control','onkeyup'=> 'return IsAlphaNumeric(event)')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'parentCategory'); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'parentCategory'); ?>
    <?php if (!empty($parentCategory)){
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'parentCategory', $parentCategory, array('empty'=>Yii::t('admin','Select Parent category'),'id'=>'dropCat','onchange'=>'return dropCategory()','class'=>'form-control'));
    }else{
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'parentCategory', array(''=>Yii::t('admin','Select Parent category')), array('id'=>'dropCat','onchange'=>'return dropCategory()','class'=>'form-control'));
    }
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'parentCategory'); ?>
        <p><?php echo Yii::t('admin','Note: To create Parent Category,Leave this drop down Empty.'); ?></p>
    </div>

<?php if(isset($model->parentCategory) && $model->parentCategory == 0 || !isset($model->parentCategory)) { ?>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom " id="itemCondition">
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'itemCondition', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'itemCondition');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $sitepaymentmodes = Myclass::getSitePaymentModes();
    if($sitepaymentmodes['exchangePaymentMode'] == "1")
    {
    ?>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="exchangetoBuy">
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'exchangetoBuy', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'exchangetoBuy');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    if($sitepaymentmodes['buynowPaymentMode'] == "1")
    {
    ?>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="buyNow">
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'buyNow', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'buyNow');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }   
    ?>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="myOffer">
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'myOffer', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'myOffer');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom " id="itemCondition" style='display:none;'>
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'itemCondition', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'itemCondition');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $sitepaymentmodes = Myclass::getSitePaymentModes();
    if($sitepaymentmodes['exchangePaymentMode'] == "1")
    {
    ?>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="exchangetoBuy" style='display:none;'>
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'exchangetoBuy', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'exchangetoBuy');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    if($sitepaymentmodes['buynowPaymentMode'] == "1")
    {
    ?>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="buyNow" style='display:none;'>
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'buyNow', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'buyNow');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }   
    ?>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="myOffer" style='display:none;'>
    <?php 

    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'myOffer', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'myOffer');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>  
    <!--div class="checkbox checkbox-custom" id="contactSeller">
    <?php 
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'contactSeller');
    echo $form->checkBox($model, 'contactSeller', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));
    ?>
    </div-->

    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('admin','Create') : Yii::t('admin','Save'),array('class' => 'btn btn-success')); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
<!-- form -->
<script>
    $("#catImage").show();
    if ($("#dropCat").val() != "") {
        $("#catImage").hide();
    } else {
        $("#catImage").show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: .... If you don't know, we don't know either. At least, I don't see the relevant code in this question. What is `$form`?

Comment: @Xorifelse I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This function allows only AlphaNumeric ( Letters, Numbers and Spaces).

```
'return IsAlphaNumeric(event)'
```

Comment: Right, that's what I figured. I tried removing that piece of code but I can't do that. The form disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onkeyup` e.g.

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours but I'm still getting the error message saying that special characters aren't allowed. Thanks.

Comment: Please check in your model field rules for this field. Is their any numeric condition for this field.